# Find li element by inner text of inside span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like below

```
<ul id="tabStripSecondaryElements" class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset" data-role="tabstrip" style="margin-left: 37px; margin-right: 40px;" role="tablist" aria-activedescendant="tab_0">
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default k-first" id="tab_1" value="1" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-1"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Automobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_3" value="3" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-2"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Router&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_4" value="4" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-3"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Smart City Sensor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_5" value="5" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-4"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> ZigBee Power Cable&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_6" value="6" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-5"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Tracker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_7" value="7" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-6"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Fleet Intelligence&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_8" value="8" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-7"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_9" value="9" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-8"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Double Door&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_87" value="87" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-10"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>

</ul>
```

I am trying to find the li element by the inner text of inside span element.

Eg: Router has the li element id - tab_1

I tried using following jquery code but it's not working and returning empty

```
$('li.k-item tabClick k-state-default span.k-link:contains("Router")');
```

Is there any other way to get this?

Comment: `$('li.k-item span.k-link:contains("Router")');` Try this <- Actually your selector is saying find a li with class `k-item` and look inside further for `tabClick` class.

Comment: Try this : $('li.k-item.tabClick.k-state-default span.k-link:contains("Router")').css('color', 'blue');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is with your selector. You have spaces between the `k-item tabClick k-state-default` classes, where they should be joined together with period delimiters for the `class` selector prefix. This will then select the `span`. To get the `li` from this you can use `closest()`:

```js
var $span = $('li.k-item.tabClick.k-state-default span.k-link:contains("Router")');

var $li = $span.closest('li');
$li.css('color', '#C00');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabStripSecondaryElements" class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset" data-role="tabstrip" style="margin-left: 37px; margin-right: 40px;" role="tablist" aria-activedescendant="tab_0">
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default k-first" id="tab_1" value="1" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-1">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Automobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_3" value="3" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-2">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Router&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_4" value="4" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-3">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Smart City Sensor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_5" value="5" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-4">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      ZigBee Power Cable&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_6" value="6" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-5">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Tracker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_7" value="7" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-6">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Fleet Intelligence&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_8" value="8" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-7">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_9" value="9" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-8">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Double Door&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_87" value="87" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-10">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

As an alternative to avoid `closest()` you could use `:has` to directly select the `li`:

```js
var $li = $('li.k-item.tabClick.k-state-default:has(span.k-link:contains("Router"))');
$li.css('color', '#C00');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tabStripSecondaryElements" class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset" data-role="tabstrip" style="margin-left: 37px; margin-right: 40px;" role="tablist" aria-activedescendant="tab_0">
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default k-first" id="tab_1" value="1" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-1">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Automobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_3" value="3" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-2">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Router&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_4" value="4" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-3">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Smart City Sensor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_5" value="5" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-4">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      ZigBee Power Cable&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_6" value="6" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-5">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Tracker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_7" value="7" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-6">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Fleet Intelligence&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_8" value="8" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-7">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_9" value="9" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-8">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Double Door&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_87" value="87" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-10">
    <span class="k-loading k-complete"></span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> 
      Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span>
    </span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a **Pure JavaScript** approach, you can use the **[textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property to retrieve the text from inside each `li` element and then use the **[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** method to check if the element's text contains the string or not.

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".k-item.tabClick.k-state-default");

x.forEach(li => {
  if(li.textContent.indexOf("Router") != -1){
    li.style.color = "red";
    return li;
  }
});
```

---

You can make a re-usable function say, `checkText()` for checking different strings too by just passing a string as a parameter and comparing each element's text content with that string instead.

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of this reusable function:

```js
/* JavaScript */

var x = document.querySelectorAll(".k-item.tabClick.k-state-default");

function checkText(e) {
  x.forEach(li => {
    if(li.textContent.indexOf(e) != -1){
      console.log(e + " is found and has been marked red!!");
      li.style.color = "red";
      return li;
    }
  });
}

checkText("Router");
checkText("Mobile");
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<ul id="tabStripSecondaryElements" class="k-tabstrip-items k-reset" data-role="tabstrip" style="margin-left: 37px; margin-right: 40px;" role="tablist" aria-activedescendant="tab_0">
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default k-first" id="tab_1" value="1" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-1"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Automobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_3" value="3" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-2"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Router&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_4" value="4" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-3"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Smart City Sensor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_5" value="5" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-4"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> ZigBee Power Cable&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_6" value="6" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-5"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Tracker&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_7" value="7" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-6"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Fleet Intelligence&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_8" value="8" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-7"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Mobile&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_9" value="9" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-8"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Double Door&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>
   <li class="k-item tabClick k-state-default" id="tab_87" value="87" role="tab" aria-controls="tabStripSecondaryElements-10"><span class="k-loading k-complete"></span><span unselectable="on" class="k-link"> Test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></span></span></li>

</ul>
```